# SQL join query not returning anything

Tags: c#, sql, join, inner-join

I am trying to make a query using a join statement. This is what I have:

```
SELECT Person.Id,  
      Person.AddressLine1, Person.AddressLine2, Person.Name, 
      Person.City
  FROM Person WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
      Customer ON 
      Customer.Id = Person.Id
  WHERE (Person.IsRegular = 1)
```

But when I use this (I added another parameter in the WHERE clause):

```
SELECT Person.Id,  
      Person.AddressLine1, Person.AddressLine2, Person.Name, 
      Person.City
  FROM Person WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
      Customer ON 
      Customer.Id = Person.Id
  WHERE (Person.IsRegular = 1) AND
      (Customer.RoleType = 'XX') AND 
      (Customer.LocType = 3)
```

There's no result even if I have a row in my Customer table that matches the Person.Id and that specific row has a field in which RoleType="XX" and LocType=3.

UPDATE: 
fixed it, but now i am having a problem.. i did this:

```
SELECT Person.Id, Person.AddressLine1, Person.AddressLine2, Person.Name, Person.City 
FROM Person WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.Id = Person.Id WHERE (Person.IsRegular = 1) AND (Customer.RoleType = 'XX') AND (Customer.LocType = 3) 
AS xxx ON xxx.Id=1... it says:incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'
```

Comment: Does the person with the specific PersonID, the RoleType 'xx' and LocType 3 have the attribute IsRegular set to 1?

Comment: is there a reason you are using the `WITH (NOLOCK)` ?

Comment: fixed it man, but now i am having a problem.. i did this: SELECT Person.Id, Person.AddressLine1, Person.AddressLine2, Person.Name, Person.City FROM Person WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.Id = Person.Id WHERE (Person.IsRegular = 1) AND (Customer.RoleType = 'XX') AND (Customer.LocType = 3) AS xxx ON xxx.Id=1... it says:incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `INNER JOIN` with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in your second `SELECT` to see what is actually being detected in the `Customer` table, and if it is what you expect.

Check data types: is, for instance, RoleType a `CHAR` field (with padding) instead of `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Either that or use `LIKE '%XX%'` on the RoleType

Comment: fixed it man, but now i am having a problem.. i did this:

SELECT Person.Id,  
      Person.AddressLine1, Person.AddressLine2, Person.Name, 
      Person.City
  FROM Person WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
      Customer ON 
      Customer.Id = Person.Id
  WHERE (Person.IsRegular = 1) AND
      (Customer.RoleType = 'XX') AND 
      (Customer.LocType = 3)
  AS xxx ON xxx.Id=1...

it says:incorrect  syntax near the keyword 'AS'

Comment: AS is an alias keyword to be used either 1) for columns in your SELECT (e.g. SELECT col1 as myCol1...) or 2) for a derived table, but not on terms within a WHERE clause.

Comment: yes.. i am trying to do a derived table here... how can i correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Should you be joining customerid to personid?  Or is there a personid column in the customer table?  Those may not match up...
One of those tables is likely to contain the foreign key.
Something like:

```
SELECT Person.Id,         
Person.AddressLine1, 
Person.AddressLine2, Person.Name,        
Person.City   
FROM Person WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN Customer ON
Customer.Id = Person.CustomerId   
WHERE (Person.IsRegular = 1)
```

Depending on how your tables are laid out, this could be

```
Customer.PersonId = Person.Id
```

Comment: Customers are Persons, so that is possible, with a 1-1 relationship.

Comment: True enough-- Though based on the given info, there is still no guarantee that their primary keys will match.

Comment: fixed it man, but now i am having a problem.. i did this: SELECT Person.Id, Person.AddressLine1, Person.AddressLine2, Person.Name, Person.City FROM Person WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.Id = Person.Id WHERE (Person.IsRegular = 1) AND (Customer.RoleType = 'XX') AND (Customer.LocType = 3) AS xxx ON xxx.Id=1... it says:incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

Comment: that is because AS gives an alias to something (like a column, table or subquery).  You are assigning it to the where clause, which doesn't work.  What is your end goal?

Comment: to have a derived table from the join tables in make an alias for it...and then, filter it through the alias..like aliasName.Id=1

Comment: do you want a temp table or a just something held in memory.  If in memory, just put parens around it: "Select A.ID from (select ID from table) AS A"

Comment: select * into #yourtemptable from (your query here)